# Hahn Banach theorem proof

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be real linear space and $X_{0}$ is its subspace. Also let $p$ be a finite convex functional in $X$ and $f_{0}$ is linear functional in $X_{0}$, while

$f_{0}(x)\le p(x),x\in X_{0}$

Then exists linear functional $f$ defined in $X$, which is extension of functional $f_{0}$ a for which is this true

$f(x)\le p(x),x\in X$

I am having a problem to understand little detail in the following proof

Assume $X\neq X_{0}$. We will show it is possible to exnted $f_{0}$ to some bigger subspace $X'$ while conserving $f'(x)\le p(x),x\in X'$.

Let $y,z\in X_{0}$. Then according to $f_{0}(x)\le p(x)$ and convexivity of $p$ $\forall u\in X$ we have

$-f_{0}(z)+p(z+u)\ge -f_{0}(y)-p(-y-u) $

Let

$c_{1}(u)=inf \{-f_{0}(z)+p(z+u):z\in X_{0}\}$

$c_{2}(u)=sup \{-f_{0}(y)-p(-y-u):y\in X_{0}\}$

How do you prove that $c_{1} \ge c_{2}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to show that $$-f_{0}(z)+p(z+u)\ge -f_{0}(y)-p(-y-u)$$
for every $y,z\in X_0$. But $$f_0(z)-f_0(y)=f_0(z+u)+f_0(-y-u)
\le p(z+u)+p(-y-u).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm sorry I don't follow, functionals isn't my strength. I was told to choose a settled ( not changing) y and the right handside is a specific number, but I couldn't figure out how to continue. Could you write some explaining to your answer please?

Comment: @Crash I don't understand how you think what I wrote is different from what you were told to do. Saying "It's enough to show A for every y in X" is the same as saying "Fix y in X. Then A".

Comment: Oh I see it now, I apologize, thanks again

Comment: @Crash No problem - certainly nothing to apologize for.